# Microsoft ntlm client for Centos 8?

Tags: ntlm, centos8

I my network, all windows clients connect to the internet through a Microsoft TMG web proxy using the TMG official ntlm client.
But Linux devices have problem with ntlm.
How can I install an ntlm client in CentOS8 to connect it to the internet?

ps: I couldn't install cntlm on centos 8 which is not connected to the internet.